# Guice and 'injection' of the Injector

Tags: java, singleton, instance, guice, cdi

I tryied Google Guice after reading this article : http://tech.puredanger.com/2007/07/03/pattern-hate-singleton/

But there is something I didn't understand : when you use the @Singleton anotation of Guice, the injection inject the same instance, but only for one Injector.

If I create an other Injector somewhere else, the @Singletion doesn't works (as stated in the documentation).

So I will have to pass the injector instance everywhere in my code, or make it available in a singleton.

And this is exactly I would like to avoid.

How to we manage injectorS to make it possible to return the same instance everytime ?

Thanks.

Comment: > If I create an other Injector somewhere else

Why are you creating other injectors?

Comment: @mlk because I tryied Guice by following this tutorial : http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/GettingStarted and they build object by invoking getInstance on the injector. But I don't think that that injector must be passed everywhere in my application.

Comment: What you should try to have is a single tree of objects and in the main you have a bootstrap class that gets the world going.

Answer (score 3):

Code using Guice shouldn't normally need to access the injector itself: objects will receive either their dependencies or a `Provider<T>` for their dependencies, if they need to construct more than one.

Usually, objects only need the injector if they have dependencies but aren't themselves created by the injector (so they can't have their dependencies injected).  If you're using Guice everywhere, you probably only need to do that on application start-up.  If you're only using Guice for part of your project, the injector becomes a single singleton that proxies for all the other singletons you're now accessing through it.

Do note that classes annotated `@Singleton` are still singleton objects, albeit without some of the baggage associated with non-injected singletons.  You should still try to avoid depending on them too much.